# RegEx: Handling subgroups of Big - OR - Group as individuals and not as group count together

Tags: java, python, regex

Let's say I have this pattern:

```
(?:StackOverflow is (.*)|(.*) is StackOverflow)
```

I am using Java or Python. But I think they work quite similar.

My Input Strings would be:

```
StackOverflow is great
```

or

```
great is StackOverflow
```

In the real use case, I don't know the pattern and I don't know the input String. Both are set by the user.

I've tested it with regex101.com .

The result looks like this:

`StackOverflow is great` : Group 0 is `great`

`great is StackOverflow` : Group 1 is `great`

However I need both times to have Group 0 be `great` .
So what I'm trying to achieve is: Only count those groups, that actually exist in the input strings. Any other part of the big surrounding OR - group should be ignored.

I searched already on the internet but I don't really know what to search for in this case.

Is there a way to do this in RegEx?

Comment: Does it have to be group 1 or does it just have to be the _same_ group both times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, regex doesn't work that way. Groups are numbered from left to right and there's nothing you can do about it.

That said, the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for python does it differently. It would consider both of these groups as #1. Unfortunately I don't know if such a thing exists for Java.

However, I think the *real* solution here is for the user to input a different regex. For example, your regex could be written as `(StackOverflow is )?(.+)(?(1)| is StackOverflow)`, which is functionally equivalent except the word you're matching will always be in group #2. (Of course, this solution doesn't work if the word absolutely must be captured in group #1.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will think about how I can get my user to write this. ;-)